# Continuous functions and infinity

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, for $\forall \delta>0, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x+n\delta)=+\infty$. Is it correct that $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$?

Comment: Hm, I find the question quite reasonable and not obvious. Usually we do not close questions of such level.

Comment: @叶胥达  the tag "functional-analysis" is not very appropriate for this question; "real-analysis" would fit better

Comment: and the tag 'counterexamples' is a posteriori misleading

Comment: Sorry about that...I am new here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is true and well known. One of the references I know is the problem book of B. Makarov, M. Goluzina, A. Lodkin and A. Podkorytov (Selected problems in real analysis, Translations of Mathematical Monographs 107, AMS 1992), problem II.1.25 (it is slightly different, but essentially the same).

An idea is that if, on the contrary, there are intervals $\Delta_k=[x_k,y_k]$ onto which $f$ is bounded, $x_k\to \infty$, then we may construct a nested family of closed intervals $T_i$, $T_1\supset T_2\supset T_3\dots$, and positive integers $n_1<n_2<\dots$, such that each interval of the form $n_iT_i$ is contained in some $\Delta_k$. Then for a common point $t=\cap T_i$ it appears that $f(nt)$ does not tend to infinity.

Comment: If we remove the continuity hypothesis, what's a counterexample?

Comment: take rationally independent numbers $x_1<x_2<\dots$ tending to infinity, define $f(x_i)=0$, $f(t)=t$ for $t\notin \{x_i\}$. Each arithmetic progression contains at most two $x$'s, so the limits along it equals infinity.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, in fact, 
$$\inf_{\delta>0}\ \liminf_{n\to\infty}f(n\delta) =\liminf_{x\to+\infty}f(x).$$
Assuming w.l.o.g.  $\liminf_{x\to+\infty}f(x)<\alpha<+\infty$, the open set $A=\{f<\alpha\}$ is unbounded. Therefore, for any non-empty open interval $(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}_+$ and any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the set $\cup_{k> n}(ka,kb)$, that contains a right-unbounded interval, meets $A$. Equivalently, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the open set $ B_n:=\cup_{k> n}{1\over k}A$ meets $(a,b)$, so that $B_n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}_+$. By the Baire category theorem $\cap_{n\ge0}B_n$ is not empty, actually dense, meaning that there exist $\delta>0$ such that $n\delta\in A$ for infinitely many $n$, an this means $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f(n\delta)\le\alpha.$ Being $\alpha$ arbitrary, the claim follows.

Comment: With a sligthly smaller, open unbounded set $A$ one shows that actually $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f(n\delta)=\liminf_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ holds for a dense set of $\delta>0$.